# Error installing composer

Tags: php, composer-php

When I try to install composer with:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

It's first telling me acces denied then when I do:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

It will move to that directory. When I try composer in my terminal 
all the possible composer commands show up.

But when I for example do:

> composer dump-autoload

It's telling me:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/local/bin To
>   initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described
>   in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

But my composer.phar is in that directory! What should I do?

Comment: You need to be in the project directory for your own project with a composer.json file for your own project to use most of the composer commands

Comment: Oke, I'm using Laravel in what directory should I place this?

Comment: Have you read the Laravel installation notes - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1

Comment: I've red it but I don't fully understand it. I've installed composer in /usr/local/bin/composer. I've also put composer.phar in the root of my laravel project. Still not working. Could you please give some explanation?

Comment: Don't move composer.phar anywhere once it's installed..... composer is a tool, not part of the laravel application..... you use composer to install Laravel as per the docs

Comment: Yes, but I don't need a clean install of Laravel. I"ve copied a project from my pc to my mac but now it's not working anymore with composer.

Comment: What happens when you cd to your laravel project folder, and run composer install?

Comment: It's telling me: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: Then what's your problem? It's worked! What did you expect to happen?

Comment: But when I want to add a class to my composer.json file and for example I give the wrong namespace. And I do composer dumpautoload it won't throw an error. Sow I guess something is still wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99711/discussion-between-jamie-and-mark-baker).

Comment: Your issue is nothing to do with composer, it's to do with your composer.json file, and the classes that you're including through that (why are you adding anything to composer.json unless it's to tell composer to load it through packagist).... but surely you're just building a laravel app, so what are you adding to composer.json?

Comment: I'm adding this:    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/mailers",
            "app/classes/upload"
        ]
    },      so I can use custom classes.